# Поиск по нескольким полям

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, backend

У меня есть База данных MySQL. Есть таблица users со следующей структурой:

- user_id
- first_name
- last_name
- middle_name
- birthdate
- document

Есть одно поле поиска на странице. Сейчас поиск работает через SQL LIKE таким образом

```
    public static function getTableDataBySearch($search) {

    $sql = "
    SELECT * FROM " . self::$table . " WHERE first_name  LIKE '%".$search."%'
        OR last_name LIKE '%".$search."%'
        OR middle_name LIKE '%".$search."%'
        OR birthdate LIKE '%".$search."%'
        OR birthdate LIKE '%".$search."%'
        OR documentLIKE '%".$search."%'
        ORDER BY number";

   return \R::getAssoc($sql);
}
```

Однако, если ввести в поле поиска одновременно фамилию и имя, или ФИО и дату рождения, то соответственно ничего не будет найдено.
Как это можно улучшить?

> P.S. До момента написания этого вопроса, я прочитал охожие вопросы,
> однако те решения либо неясны мне, либо устаревшие.

Comment: Всё наоборот, это приведённое в ЭТОМ вопросе решение как раз и устаревшее

Comment: Как его можно улучшить?

Comment: Для начала защитить от SQL инъекций